# how do I alternate the float on consecutive database entires?

Tags: php, image, css-float, alternate

[My Website](http://kiddiessupportscheme.org/newsite/index2.php?op=The%20Kids)

As you can see on the above link there are several 'kids', the information for each one is grabbed from a database.

I want to make each alternating image float to the left, so that the images go left, then right, then left etc. At the moment they all float left. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$query="SELECT id, title, text, media, media2, thumb, deleted FROM kids ORDER BY id DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        if($row['deleted'] == 0) {

echo '<div id="'.$row['title'].'">';
echo '<img src="images/'.$row['media'].'" class="floatLeftClear" id="border" />';
if($row['media2'] != "") {
echo '<img src="images/'.$row['media2'].'" class="floatLeftClear" id="border" />';
}

echo '<p id="text">';
echo '<span class="kisstitle">'.$row['title'].'</span><br>';
echo $row['text'];
echo '</p>';
echo ' <p align="center" id="spererater"><img src="images/seperater.jpg" width="900" height="5" /><a href="index2.php?op=The Kids#top">Top</a><br /></p>';
}}
?>
```

I tried to check the ID, if even, float left, if odd, float right, but I couldn't work out how to do it, plus the ID may not always be even / odd alternating so I'd rather find a different solution if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a counter variable, increment by one each time you're looping over an item -- and use that counter with a modulo, to determiner whether you are on an even or odd line :

```
$counter = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if (($counter % 2) == 0) {
        // even
    } else {
        // odd
    }

    // use the data of the current $row, display it

    $counter++; // increment the counter, for next iterator
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter. Before loop `$i = 0;` and inside loop `$i++`, `if ($i % 2 == 0) { // odd} else {// even}`